# Is it possible to select all id's without a while-loop

Tags: php, mysql, loops

I'm not sure if there is an answer for this, but I was thinking about the fact that PHP isn't very fast with while loops. That got me thinking about a basic function, which does something like this:

```
$array = array();
$sItem = DB::cms_query("SELECT id FROM someTable");
while($fItem = $sItem->fetch_assoc() ){
    $array[] = $fItem['id']; // store the id in an array
}
```

That will give me an array with all found id's. What I was wondering is this:

Is it possible to select all those id's in 1 query and only use one fetch (so no loops to fetch), without creating difficult code. The goal is a simple piece of code to select all id's.

*Small edit: I could replace `fetch_assoc()` with `fetch_row()` to improve a tiny bit, but I'm looking to replace the loop*

**To answer some questions:**
I'm using **mysqli**, in my own custom database class (I'm new to OO, so in time I might improve that, but thats another story)

Comment: What database API are you using? PDO has `fetchAll()`, which fetches everything in one fell swoop.

Comment: It's possible, if you use PDO. It fetches all results into an array which you can loop with whatever approach you choose. As for php being slow with while loops.. define slow. 1ms?

Comment: Use GROUP_CONCAT in your database query so that only one row containing all IDs is returned, not a row for each ID.... but the while loop is incredibly fast in comparison with the actual query execution, so this really is a micro-optimisation

Comment: @Barmar: nope, mylsqi. N.B.: Not really sure at what to define 'slow', its more hypothetical, and about trying some different approaches

Comment: If you're using mysqli, then the answer is no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the mysqli extension doesn't provide any way to fetch all rows with a single operation, you can only fetch them one at a time. The only PHP API that currently offers this feature is PDO.

Answer (score 0):

> > but I was thinking about the fact that php isnt very fast with while loops

How much ids are you fetching and what is called "not fast" for you?

I think the reason for a bad performance would most likely not be a while loop, but some other glitch with your code...

Comment: The code itself isnt slow. Im at a point where I've got the big steps covered, and moving on to a bit more complex understanding of the code, to improve the small steps (not too early in the proccess offcourse :P )